# ¿Cómo puedo realizar mi consulta para que tome los 20 últimos registros en mi base de datos postgreSql con HQL?

Tags: java, jquery, angularjs, hql

De los registros que tengo en mi base solamente necesito visualizar mis últimos 20 registros.

Mi consulta actualmente se encuentra así:

```
   @Query("SELECT a FROM Audit a ORDER BY a.whenau DESC")   
   public List<Audit> findAll();
```

He intentado con Limit pero eso no está soportado por HQL.
¿Cuál sería la mejor opción en este caso?

Gracias.

Comment: Podrías intentar condicionar que traiga los registros cuyo ID sea mayor a 990, así te traerá los últimos 10. No se si resuelva tu duda, quizás podrías ser un poco mas especifica con el objetivo de querer extraer los últimos registros.

Comment: @sstan Concuerdo, por ello comentaba que dependía de la situación en la que la chica se encontrara podría aplicarse o no.

Comment: Gracias, he editado mi pregunta.

Comment: ¿Estás usando Spring Data? Si es el caso, ¿cual versión?

Comment: tengo las siguientes librerias dentro de mi proyecto: spring-data-commons-1.12.1.RELEASE.jar, spring-data-commons-core-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar y spring-data-jpa-1.10.1.RELEASE.jar. No sé si eso responda la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar Query.setMaxResults() que es lo mismo que LIMIT en SQL; está configurando la cantidad máxima de filas que desea devolver.

Comment: Gracias, si me podrías ayudar con la sintaxis? no he conseguido hacerlo con esta opción, que al parecer es la que mas se acerca.

Comment: Checa este ejemplo -> https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-limit-the-hibernate-query-result/